# How to change a component value on hierarchical structure in altium

Tags: altium

I designed a Hierarchical structure in Altium. I need a component value becomes different from other sheets. However, by changing the value all other sheets get the same value. As you can see by changing a resistor value on TCP sheet other sheets change the value of their components based on the other sheets. How can I solve this problem?
[image]

Comment: that doesn't sound a problem, but the whole purpose of the feature "hierarchical structure". Have you read Altium docs on this?

Comment: A bit like *I want two resistor values to have the same value but also have a different value*

Answer (score 1):

You need every used resistor value as individual component with their own Manufacturer Partnumber and value in your lib.

Then it is possible via the "Variant Management". You can define here assembly variants for every component wehe for example:
R20_1.TCP1 is component A (10k) (Default)
R20_1.TCP2 is component B (100R)
R20_1.UDP1 is not populated
R20_1.UDP2 is component C (1R)

1st create an assembly variant via right mouse click on the project -> Variants

Then

1. Select the TCP2 sheet (left mouse click right of the Editor string)
2. right mouse click on the Component R20_1.TCP2 -> Part Actions ->
   Choose Alternate Part.
3. Then select the "Component B" with value 100R from your lib.

In the schematic PDF print you need to seleck to draw the Physical structure of the assembly variant